# How to make CSS columns in a div?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am prototyping a Wordpress template and I'm trying to place the same elements on the `header` like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/768097/about.pdf

Here are the HTML and CSS files: http://acreedy.oliveandpickle.com/

I need 4 columns in the `header` and everything should be placed under the images.

Comment: This link does not work anymore. Can you upload the files to a different source for future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="header">

  <h1>Alan Creedy</h1>

    <ul id="quickInfo">
      <li class="mission">Mission Statement</li>
        <li>Helping People Think for Themselves</li>
        <li>1.919.926.0688</li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Email Me</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#BestPracticeIdeas">Best Practice Ideas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ManagementTools">Management Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Preneed">Preneed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#CaseStudies">Case Studies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#RecommendedResources">Recommended Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#ThinkTankForum">Think Tank Forum</a></li>    
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  border-bottom:3px solid #1582AB;
  height:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:46px 0 0;
  width:1000px;
  position:relative;
}
#header h1 {
  background:url("images/alan_creedy_headshot_transparent.png") no-repeat left top;
  font-size:40px;
  height:140px;
  padding:8px 0 0 215px;
  margin:0;
}
#quickInfo {
  position:absolute;
  right:10px;
  top:10px;
  width:400px;
}
#quickInfo li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
.mission {
  font-size:18px;
}
#menu {
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:0;
  width:1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating left will most certainly fix your issue, though keep in mind whenever you add padding or margin to your floated element that you will have to adjust your width as well. I checked out your page and you didn't compensate that change. Fix the width accordingly and you should be good to go :D

~ Chris

http://twitter.com/TheCSSGuru

Comment: So, float left on all the header elements?

Comment: I would just rearrange your html and css a bit more, too large to paste here, but ill make another answer with what I think you should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using html5 then you could use aside or section elements instead of div's.

```
<style>
    .column {
             float: left;
             width: 200px;}
</style>

<aside class="column">
  Column1
</aside>
<section class="column">
  Column2
</section>
<section class="column">
  Column3
</section>
<section class="column">
  Column4
</section>
```

Comment: True True, it should be ok with a little JavaScript though to give IE a kick up the backside. 
 <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->